# Run tensorflow remotely on google cloud and then get back accuracy/predictions

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a gui in python where the user choses training data, and then by pressing the train button trains a neural network.Then the user can get the test accuracy or use the model to predict something.

The problem is that I cant train a neural network  in my pc because of not enough gpu. I want to upload training files in **Google Cloud** and then run remotely a python script that trains a model in google cloud and and then gets back the training accuracy , or gives for example a picture in google cloud storage and runs something like predict.py remotely that predicts the label  of the picture using the previously trained model (that I have saved for example in google cloud storage)

So far I have found how to access google bucket from python remotely but I don't know how to run a python script remotely (for example using google.cloud lirbaries?) 
and then take back the output.

Any ideas on how can that be done ? Thank you !

Comment: Read about tensorflow serving, or just fire up an instance and make an api out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you to have a look at [Cloud Machine Learning Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/). This product of the Google Cloud Platform family looks like a really nice fit for what you want to do, as it allows you to train models in the cloud, keep them there, and run predictions based on the input data of your choice, with the models you already trained. As of now, it works with *TensorFlow* (which I think is what you are planning on using, as you are working with Neural Networks), and just recently, *scikit-learn* and *XGBoost* were introduced as a beta release.

Let me share with you some documentation references that you may find useful in order to start working with ML Engine, but I encourage you to navigate through the documentation in order to get more familiar with this service:

- [Training Models](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/training-steps): a list of requirements, best-practices, and processes to train a model in Cloud ML Engine. You can configure your trainer to use [GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-gpus) (or even the recently released [TPUs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-tpus)) in order to improve performance, and you can use hyperparameter tuning to obtain the best of your models.
- [Deploying Models](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models): you can export your trained model to a `SavedModel`, load it into the Cloud and get it ready for serving prediction requests.
- [Running Predictions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/prediction-overview): you can run two types of prediction jobs: *batch* (optimized to handle high volumes of data with complex models) or *online* (optimized to minimize latency). Batch prediction can also be used to run models stored in Cloud Storage locations.
- [Use Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/working-with-cloud-storage) as your main storage location. ML Engine is optimized to work with GCS. You will be able to upload your input data and models in GCS, and process that data using ML Engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to train models on remotely (e.g. GPU instances from AWS), try this library:

```
!pip install aibro==0.0.45 --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple

from aibro.train import fit
machine_id = 'g4dn.4xlarge' #instance name on AWS
job_id, trained_model, history = fit(
    model=model,
    train_X=train_X,
    train_Y=train_Y,
    validation_data=(validation_X, validation_Y),
    machine_id=machine_id
)
```

Tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19sXZ4kbic681zqEsrl_CZfB5cegUwuIB#scrollTo=ERqoHEaamR1Y